# How do we generalize limitations on the propagation speed of sinusoidal waves to limitations for transmitting any kind of information?

Tags: electromagnetism, velocity, relativity

Our calculations on EM waves basically deal with harmonic waves and through such calculations and relations, we derive some relations and limitations for wave like phenomena. Of these relations are group and phase velocity of a wave. We impose some limitations on how great this velocity (e.g. for an EM wave) could be.

But how could (and why) we generalize such limitations ( like the one on the propagation speed of sinusoidal waves) to limitations for transmitting any kind of information?

Plus: What is the precise definition of "information" (which we always say it can not travel faster than C )??

Comment: See [group velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity#Physical_interpretation)

Comment: @Trimok: Yeah, I had a look at it. Thank you. Like what you lead me to read, I guess the answer is what "Wave–particle duality" talks about... I didn't know much about it.. though I believe it's interesting to hear different ideas and view points specially on this physics forum in addition to what we find on other websites like wikipedia.